# How do I escape greater than (>) for display on label when using Angular without using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates, angular-directive

I have a data that contains < and >, I want to show this characters avoiding the innerHTML because I have a couple of checkboxs in the label (Also the content is not HTML). The data comes from a JSON.

```
const labelContent = ' > 1 '; // only for desmostration
```

Template:

```
 <label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    {{labelContent}}
 <label>
```

Current output:

```
&lt; 1
```

I want to know if is possible to show this data.

Comment: Are you using AngularJS or Angular2?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? Because it is working fine for me [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gilango/ys7evcmj/1/)